# Is it possible to publish the raster contents of a directory as an ESRI 10.3 Image service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, image-service

I am currently experimenting for the first time with ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 and have been told that I can publish contents of a directory (TIF Aerial Images)as an Image Service. In the ESRI Help I can not however see this option.

Can anyone confirm that this can or cannot be done?